# make iOS plugin to open camera and photo gallery from unity

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I have game in unity and I want to let the user change the background from camera or photo gallery in IOS, I know that I have to make library in objective c , and I know how to open the camera or photo gallery in objective c using this code

```
-(void)getImage{

    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

}


- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *) picker {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
}

- (void)imagePickerController : (UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)imageProfile editingInfo:(NSDictionary *) editingInfo
{

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

but how to use this code in objective c library

Comment: If you just want to open the Photo Gallery / Photo Album and select a image you might want to have a look at : http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/introducing-native-gallery-assist-ios-android-editor-emulator.403459/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the Camera Picker for Unity for a image gallery i suggest you to write a plugin wrapping the API you are describing yourself. Something like :

```
extern "C" char* _ImagePickerOpen ( int type, bool frontFacingIsDefault, char* callbackName ) {
```

Then inside ImagePickerOpen you should be able to initialize the Gallery with the code you already provided yourself.

When an image has been picked i suggest you to use something like this code to save the image to the disk and return the url for unity to use it. This is one approach but you can also base64 encode it and return it as one big string.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage*)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary*)info {
callCount++;

// Image :
image = [self scaleAndRotateImage:image];

// Image data:
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.6);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path=[[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp.jpg"];

NSString *fileUri=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:%@?ori=%d&cnt=%d",path,image.imageOrientation,callCount];

strcpy( fileUriStr, (char*)[fileUri UTF8String] );

[imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

self.lastImageUri = fileUri;
[self.imagePicker.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

UnityGaleryCallback( fileUri );}
```

The code above is from a plugin which we made at one time. If you are looking to use the ImagePicker to take photos with Apple's buildin photo functionality and not only gallery i suggest you to look into something like Camera Capture Kit - ( https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/56673 )as well since that should allow you abit more control on the image captured.